# Ground Truth Image to One Hot Encoded Array (Semantic Segmentation)

Tags: numpy, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm creating my own Dataset for People and Street Segmentation. Below, you see a labled Ground Truth (GT) Image.

[image: Ground Truth]

In the past I did a simple Regression between the model output and the GT Image (in the past I only used Streets). Now I read, Cross Entropy Loss is more common in that case. Since, my GT and also the model output Image has the same width *w* and height *h* as the input image, I have to create an array of size *h* x *w* x *c*, where *c* is the number of classes (in my case 3, background, street, people). I think, this is called One-Hot-Encoded Array.

I solved this as follows:

```py
        for height in range(len(img_as_np_array)):
            for width in range(len(img_as_np_array[0])):
                temp = np.zeros(classes)
                if get_class(img_as_np_array[height,width]) == 1:
                    temp[1] = 1
                    one_hot_label[height,width] = temp
                if get_class(img_as_np_array[height,width]) == 2:
                    temp[2] = 1
                    one_hot_label[height,width] = temp
```

where the method get_class(channels) decides the pixel class by the color of the pixel.

```py
def get_class(channels):
    threshold = 40
    # Class 1 corresponds to streets, roads
    if channels[0] in np.arange(243-threshold,243+threshold,1) and \
        channels[1] in np.arange(169-threshold,169+threshold,1) and \
        channels[2] in np.arange(0,threshold,1):
        return 1

    # Class 2 corresponds to people
    if channels[0] in np.arange(0,threshold,1) and \
        channels[1] in np.arange(163-threshold,163+threshold,1) and \
        channels[2] in np.arange(232-threshold,232+threshold,1):
        return 2

    # Class 0 corresponds to background respectively other things
    return 0
```

I have two questions:

1. My approach is very slow (about 3 minutes for a Full HD Image), is there a way to speed this up?
2. I noticed that the colors differ in the sense of channel values. For example, orange should be [243,169,0] (RGB), but I found entries like this [206,172,8] or even this [207,176,24] could that happen, because I store my labels as jpg? Is there a better way to find the orange and blue pixels than my idea above with the threshold?

**EDIT:**

I solved the first question by my self. This takes 2 or 3 seconds for an Full HD Image:

```py
threshold = 40
class_1_shape_cond_1 = (img_as_array[:, :, 0] >= 243 - threshold) * (img_as_array[:, :, 0] <= 243 + threshold)
class_1_shape_cond_2 = (img_as_array[:, :, 1] >= 171 - threshold) * (img_as_array[:, :, 1] <= 171 + threshold)
class_1_shape_cond_3 = (img_as_array[:, :, 2] >= 0) * (img_as_array[:, :, 2] <= threshold)
class_1_shape = (class_1_shape_cond_1 * class_1_shape_cond_2 * class_1_shape_cond_3)
```

Then I do the same for class 2 and for class 3 (everything else) I can do:

```py
class_3_shape = 1 - (class_1_shape + class_2_shape)
```

After that I have to adjust the type with:

```py
class_1_shape = class_1_shape.astype(np.uint8)
class_2_shape = class_2_shape.astype(np.uint8)
class_3_shape = class_3_shape.astype(np.uint8)
```

Question 2 is still an open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Do NOT save labels as JPEG images!

jpeg is a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) method - that is, it is designed to save images using fewer bits even if it changes a bit the pixel values as long as it "looks good" to a human observer.
This is NOT the case for training labels stored as images! You cannot afford inaccuracies in the labels. You must use a [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) method, e.g., [png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Better still, store your labels as [indexed RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54929757/1714410) images to begin with and save you all the trouble of inferring the discrete labels from the RGB values.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem
If you are using Tensorflow framework, tf provides a function to generate one-hot matrix rapidly.

```py
tf.one_hot(
    indices,#your image with label
    depth, #the number of classes
    on_value=None,
    off_value=None,
    axis=None,
    dtype=None,
    name=None
)
```

for more details, see (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot?version=stable)

Comment: Thanks, I solved it already and I'm using Pytorch. However, nice to know.